# jQuery $(window).unload() fails when trying to close window

Tags: php, jquery

I am replacing model windows with full-screen overlays for smaller devices. Assuming $(window).hide() unnecessarily keeps that window in memory, I am attempting to use $(window).unload(), which is not working as expected. I am using a PHP variable for the script name, as different scripts will use this utility.

On exploring a little more, I find that unload() has been deprecated, and perhaps was not intended to be used this way in the first place. I don't know what alternative there might be, other that $(window).hide.

This is the entire code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $Script = $_REQUEST[Script];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
            .Leave {position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="Leave" src="images/CloseButton2.png" alt="close">
        <div id="ScreenOverlay"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#ScreenOverlay").load("<?PHP echo($Script); ?>", function(response, status, xhr)
                {
                    if(status == "error")
                    {
                        console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
                $(".Leave").click(function()
                {
                    $(window).unload();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the expected behaviour? You do not unload the window from memory by calling unload. [unload expects an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event)

Perhaps you wanted

```
$(".Leave").click(function()  $(window).close() });
```

***assuming you opened the window yourself from script from same origin***

There is no such thing as window.hide

If you just want to unload the content of `$("#ScreenOverlay")` then do `$("#ScreenOverlay").empty()` or `$("#ScreenOverlay").remove()`

Comment: Yeah - just edited my question after finding the function has been deprecated and was not intended to be used as I had thought. Checking close()

Comment: humm ... That doesn't seem to work either.  It's definitely seeing the click.

Comment: "assuming you opened the window yourself" (and from same origin)

Comment: @RationalRabbit Is this an X/Y problem? If you just want to unload the content of `$("#ScreenOverlay")` then do `$("#ScreenOverlay").empty()` or `$("#ScreenOverlay").remove()`

Comment: That must be the problem. What I did was create the file you see above and opened it with a query string for the file name to bring in. So, my calling program would have a link like <a href="overlay.php?Script=scriptname"> What I need to be able to do is just return to the calling script without leaving clutter in memory.

Comment: I was looking for something I could write once and use universally.

Comment: So, I assume the thing to do would be to just add a div with display:none, open it and load the file. I would think that would work.

Comment: Yes that would work, Or unload it with remove or empty